# Why do some XIBs appear to be groups containing other files, and what is the purpose of those files

Tags: iphone, objective-c

[image]

I think it is a very basic question.Some xib,plist look like a group((see this pic arrow on left)mainwindow.xib,icarouselexampleviewcontroller).New.xib file  is normal.
what is the difference between this two?
where to use?
 what is en?
 How to create them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used for Localization purposes. You can have different nibs based on the language. These just represent the different nibs for different languages. For example consider an app which has a button or image in one of its view, we can have another nib file for the same view for a different language to show the contents of the view in that specific language

go through these links

[Link 1](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LocalizingInterfaces.html&ei=hdrcTcWQLYSvrAfT8czYDg&usg=AFQjCNHCOm5lXzUBE8cMFz_Ya5I20AQdJA&sig2=dKYh-9i_Ep_mIGpblgspPg)

[Tutorial](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/09/tutorial-iphone-localization-in-xib-nib-files/)

Comment: Most of the tutorials are for Xcode 3. In Xcode 4, edit your existing XIB file. Ensure the Utilities window is shown on the right. Click the first tab in the Utilities window (the File inspector). There's a Localization section about half way down. Click the + button to add a new language.

Answer (score 0):

I guess en is used for localization. It is used when you need to create application in a different language as per client requirement.

Comment: Here is an excellent tutorial : [Localization of xib](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/09/tutorial-iphone-localization-in-xib-nib-files/)